# What is the formula to calculate fine in Indian Railways

Tags: trains, tickets, legal, indian-railways, fines

I heard that the procedure to calculate fine if caught without ticket is

```
(10 * {ticket amount}) + 25
```

I am not sure about this.

Whether it is correct or otherwise what is the formula to calculate fine in Indian Railways?

Comment: Guys, how is this off-topic? Sounds like perfectly on-topic to me.

Comment: this page enlists detailed rules: http://indiarailinfo.com/faq/post/rules-regarding-penalties-imposed-for-various-irregularities/1487#gsc.tab=0. Its an Indian Railways enthusiast's website. Quite reliable. I don't feel like copying it and pasting here...

Comment: _I don't feel like copying it and pasting here_ why @anshabhi ?

Comment: but it says that _equal amount of excess charge_ which is what I want exactly.

Comment: @JonathanReez It looks a lot like "I'm considering not buying a ticket but I need to know what the fine is, for my cost-benefit analysis" and we don't do "Help me break that law" questions. OK, it could be "The ticket system is really confusing, so I want to know how much liability I'm exposing myself to, if I get it wrong" but people with innocent motives usually mention them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indian Railways specifies the minim amount passengers will be fined for travelling without a ticket. To date (April 2017) that an excess fee (i.e. a fine) starting at 250Rs, to be added to the full ticket amount from departure (or equivalent location) to destination. Since I am having trouble loading the official Indian Railway websites, I will quote from an unofficial website ran by an enthusiast (which themselves quote from Page 281 of Southern Zone Time Table valid from July 2012):

> RULES REGARDING PENALTIES IMPOSED FOR VARIOUS IRREGULARITIES
>
> 1) Travelling without proper pass or ticket
>   Fare from the station which he has travelled or from the station which the train originally started or from the checking point with equal amount of excess charge subject to a minimum of Rs. 250/- upto the point of detection.

This [article from the Times of India](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Now-pay-Rs-250-as-fine-for-not-buying-platform-ticket-of-Rs-10/articleshow/49290492.cms) states the same:

> Forgetting to buy a platform ticket of Rs 10 will make you pay at least Rs 250 as fine.

The reason why the rules specify only the minimum fine is IMHO because Indian Railways can specify different amounts depending on factors such as the fare and the journey. The linked article talks about a specific train line (Northern Railway departing from Lucknow) on which so many travellers were caught without ticket to warrant the introduction of more severe fines.